# c# FindSumSubset(decimal, ArrayList<decimal>)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

```
ArrayList<decimal> FindSumSubset(decimal sum, ArrayList<decimal> list)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
           {
              decimal value = list[i];
              if (sum - value == 0.0m)
              {
                  return new ArrayList().Add(value);
              }
              else
              {
                  var subset = FindSumSubset(sum - value, list.GetRange(i + 1, list.Length -i);
                  if (subset != null)
                  {
                      return subset.Add(value);
                  }
              }
           }
           return null;
        }
```

i am trying to call the above function like this:

```
ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
            numbers.Add(210);
            numbers.Add(188.83);
            numbers.Add(67.93);
            numbers.Add(125.92);
            numbers.Add(35.92);
            numbers.Add(19.16);


            ArrayList listresult = new ArrayList();
            listresult = FindSumSubset(9075.12m, numbers);
```

i am getting two errors:

```
Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.FindSumSubset(decimal, ArrayList<decimal>)' has some invalid arguments
```

and

```
Error   2   Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to 'ArrayList<decimal>'
```

can someone tell me what i am diong wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `ArrayList` is no longer recommended. You should use the generic class `List<T>` instead. Change this line:

```
ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
```

to this:

```
List<decimal> numbers = new List<decimal>();
```

Also you need to fix your method declaration. The type `ArrayList<T>` doesn't even exist, so I'm not sure why that compiles. It should be this:

```
List<decimal> FindSumSubset(decimal sum, List<decimal> list)
{
    // ...
}
```

The method `List<T>.Add` returns void so you can't return the result of it, which you do in two places. For example, instead of:

```
return new ArrayList().Add(value);
```

You should do this:

```
return new List<decimal> { value };
```

You do not need to assign an empty list to your `listresult` variable and then immediately afterwards assign the result. The first assignment is entirely unnecessary. Change this:

```
ArrayList listresult = new ArrayList();
listresult = FindSumSubset(9075.12m, numbers);
```

To this:

```
List<decimal> listresult = FindSumSubset(9075.12m, numbers);
```

There are probably a lot of other errors in your code too, but this should at least get you started.

Comment: thank u so much, now i am getting an error on this line  return subset.Add(value);

Comment: @i am a girl: *The method List<T>.Add returns void so you can't return the result of it*

Comment: @i am a girl: I see you figured it out - add the element first, then afterwards return the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159844/c-why-is-my-decimal-negative