# c# why is my DECIMAL negative?

Tags: c#

here is how i call the following function:

```
    List<decimal> numbers = new List<decimal>();

    numbers.Add(210m);
    numbers.Add(188.83m);
    numbers.Add(67.93m);
    numbers.Add(125.92m);
    numbers.Add(35.92m);
    numbers.Add(19.16m);
    numbers.Add(98.48m);



    List<decimal> listresult = FindSumSubset(9075.12m, numbers);
```

*******************the function**

```
List<decimal> FindSumSubset(decimal sum, List<decimal> list)
            {
               for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
               {
                  decimal value = list[i];
                  if (sum - value == 0.0m)
                  {
                      return new List<decimal> { value };
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      var subset = FindSumSubset(sum - value, list.GetRange(i + 1, list.Count-1 -i));
                      if (subset != null)
                      {
                          subset.Add(value);
                          return subset;


                      }
                  }
               }
               return null;
            }
```

when i run in debug mode, the `decimal sum` is giving me a huge negative value like `-93435.34`

how can this be happening?

Comment: your else case is outside a for loop, is that a typo?

Comment: Check your code. You've got an else clause after a for loop.

Comment: I think I fixed the code (reverted some of the previous edit), but now `new List<decimal> { value };` won't compile.

Comment: If you can tell us in English what this is supposed to do, this will be easy..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making this change:

```
if (sum - value <= 0.0m)
```

The problem is that sum-value is not exactly 0 so it just keeps recursing forever.

Also, I think you want to remove the `for` loop.  You don't need it if you recurse.

Answer (score 0):

You're overflowing and not checking is my guess.

Comment: I don't think decimal can overflow. It's a floating point, and I think it even throws exceptions if it becomes too big instead of using an infinity value.